# Error en secuencia de escape `\t`

Tags: perl

Este *script* es del libro "VRML para Internet" (*VRML: Browsing and Building Cyberspace*) de Mark Pesce, 1995. Aunque lo tengo, el cd-rom que incluía estará en la basura hace años...

Su autor es James Waldrop, y lo llama "Datafat munger", un eliminador de precisión redundante, que apenas quita unos decimales, pero un archivo vrml tiene cientos. Un compactador, por así decirlo, creando un nuevo archivo con extensión .new.

He transcrito tal cual está impreso y mirado un ejemplar en inglés por si era una errata, y son idénticos los códigos. NO FUNCIONA, y recuerdo que de joven sí lo ejecutaba (el del cd-rom).

Me provoca error de sintaxis por el modificador `\t` de la línea 23.

¿Dónde está el error?

```perl
for ($x=-1; $x++ < $#ARGV; ) {
    $file = $ARGV[$x];
    if (! (-e $file) ) {
        print "$file not found, skipping...\n";
        next;
    }
    &convert($file);
}
exit;

sub convert {
    local ($file)= @_;
    open  (OLD, $file) || die "Couldn´t open $file: $!\n";
    open  (NEW, ">$file.new") || die "Couldn´t open $file.new: $!\n";
    while (<OLD>) {
        $line = $_;
        if (/Normal/) { while (<OLD>) { last if /}/; } Sline => ""; }
        if (/normalIndex/) { while(<OLD>) { last if /[]]/; } $line = ""; }
        $line  =~  s/[-+]?[0-9]\.[0-9]+e[+-][0-9]+/0/g;
        $line  =~  s/([-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})[0-9]+/$1/g;
        $line =~ s\0\.00/0/g;
        $line =~ s/[ ]+/ /g;
        $line =~ s/[\t]+/ /g;
        $line =~ s/^ //g;
        print NEW $line;
    }
    close OLD;
    close NEW;
}
```

Gracias si podéis ayudarme.

Answer (score 1):

El error está en la línea 21:

```
            $line =~ s\0\.00/0/g;
```

debe ser

```
            $line =~ s/0\.00/0/g;
```

Además, hay otro error unas líneas más arriba. Donde pone

```
Sline => "";
```

debe ser

```
$line = "";
```

Comment: Pues gracias, ya que perl es bastante tiquis.miquis con eso de las \\ , ¨{, etc, y me hago un lío.No soy programador. De todos modos , ahora hay otro. "Can´t modify constant item in scalar assignament in line 17".. El comando es perl mungel.pl a.wrl. (a.wrl es cualquier archivo vrml)

Comment: si le pongo if (/Normal/) { while (<OLD>) { last if /}/; } Sline => ""; }, sí funciona! MUCHAS GRACIAS, JOAQUIN! :D Esto es para una web en tree.js para modelos de juguete, y soy diseñador 3D. Reducir los modelos es clave para agilizar el acesso a la web. A.wrl pesaba 33 kb y ahora 27kb. Era sólo un simple torus- un donut...-, que con modelos más complicados puede quitar "grasa" en mayor porcentaje. Un abrazo, Joaquin.

Comment: Esto deja dos decimales.si antes era -1.840373, ahora es-1.84. Si deseo aumentar la "calidad", ¿con poner .000, o .0000, dejará esos decimales? creo que no..¿cómo variarlo para 3 o 4 decimales? si pongo .000 no afecta. sólo 2 decimales.. en $line =~ s/0\.000/0/g;

Comment: Perdón por mi ignorancia. En vrml la precisión es de 8 decimales, la simple.Si es de doble precisión, de 16, ¿cómo se haría? Hablo del caso de archivos glTF, de estructura json.

Comment: Si necesita más decimales, los puedes sacar con la función sprintf(). El problema del Sline no se arregla dejándolo como estaba, sino que lo oculta. O sea, sigue siendo un error. Pruebe a poner una '\' delante de la llave que está dentro de la expresión regular. También le podemos atender en perlenespanol.com/foro

Comment: Gracias por tu invitación. Esto a sido muy puntual. Si apenas me manejo en python, ya que uso Blender para mis trabajos.. :)